# Scala: How to create a map over a collection from a set of keys?

Tags: scala, dictionary

Say I have a set of people `Set[People]`. Each person has an age. I want to create a function, which creates a `Map[Int, Seq[People]]` where for each age from, say, 0 to 100, there would be a sequence of people of that age or an empty sequence if there were no people of that age in the original collection.

I.e. I'm doing something along the lines

```
Set[People].groupBy(_.age)
```

where the output was

```
Map[Int, Seq[People]](0 -> Seq[John,Mary], 1-> Seq[People](), 2 -> Seq[People](Bill)...
```

`groupBy` of course omits all those ages for which there are no people. How should I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've got map with not empty sequences corresponding to ages, you can fill the rest with empty collections:

```
val fullMap = (0 to 100).map (index => index -> map.getOrElse(index, None)).toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure a default value for your map:

```
val grouped = people.groupBy(_.age).withDefaultValue(Set())
```

if you need the values to be sequences you can map them

```
val grouped = people.groupBy(_.age).mapValues(_.toSeq).withDefaultValue(Seq())
```

Remember than, as the documentation puts it:

```
Note: `get`, `contains`, `iterator`, `keys`, etc are not affected by `withDefault`.
```